# Swagger UI does not load up on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, swagger-ui, nest

I've integrated swagger ui with my nestjs app. Now, on my machine, whenever I hit `localhost:3000/api` the swagger ui loads up with api docs.

But after deploying my app on EC2, when I hit `ip:port/api` the title on the tab sets to `Swagger UI` but the UI does not load. It shows a blank page.

In the network tab, I see that these swagger files are not being loaded.

[image: Swagger files not being loaded]

Comment: Are there any errors on the Console tab and Network tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: No there are no errors in the console. But in the network tab I can see some swagger files not being loaded.